# How many cubes is this tringle made of?

Tags: triangle

[image]

can you guess?

i know its a simple puzzle but lest just have fun

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My answer:

> The model can't be made from the apparent **9 cubes**.
>  It is an optical illusion that works in 2-D only.
>  It can be contrived in 3-D but not when the cubes overlap.
>
>  It is called a [**Penrose triangle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_triangle) or **tribar**, sometimes an **Escher triangle**.
>  A 3-D *illusion* [can be made](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhs4JkaW-UU) but not with proper solid cubes.